# Need ColumnA = ColumnB when ColumnC is blank, otherwise ColumnA = ColumnC

Tags: excel

Basically, need data to copy from one cell to another unless the other column has more updated information.

I.e. Need ColumnA = ColumnB when ColumnC is blank, otherwise ColumnA = ColumnC

I'm guessing this is some kind of if statement along the lines of:
=IF(C1=BLANK,B1,C1)

Comment: `=if(c1="",b1,c1)` alternatively `=if(c1<>"",c1,b1)`

Comment: Have you tried to do any research at all?

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISBLANK(C8),B8,C8)`  Try this in the A column, change the row number to reflet the one you are working on.

thanks